# Altering SQL table to add column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I currently have a table with four columns - i wanted to add a fifth column but having some trouble.

I open the table in sql server studio management 2008 and i added the column info like so:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Case]
(
    CaseId                  UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    CaseNumber              NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CourtId                 INT NOT NULL,
    DateOpened              DATETIME NOT NULL,
)
```

my addition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Case]
(
    CaseId                  UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    CaseNumber              NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CaseName                NVARCHAR(50),
    CourtId                 INT NOT NULL,
    DateOpened              DATETIME NOT NULL,
)
```

After adding CaseName column, i tried executing the table in Management Studio but i got the error message "There is already an object named 'Case' in the database."
I tried saving and then building my database hoping that the column will be added but that wasn't successful. I tried a New Query and writing the 'Alter table "case" add CaseName nvarchar(50) but again without luck. It shows that the file is changed with the new column because i saved it but after building my overall database it isn't making any changes. Any helpful tips will be great.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables sorry i just missed to add the DateOpened in the second section of my code. I want to add the CaseName column. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

You want to `ALTER`, as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Case] ADD CaseName NVARCHAR(50)
```

Better yet, you can check for the existance of the column first:

```
if not exists (SELECT 1 FROM sysobjects INNER JOIN syscolumns ON 
    sysobjects.id = syscolumns.id 
    WHERE sysobjects.name = N'Case' AND syscolumns.name = N'CaseName')
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Case] ADD CaseName NVARCHAR(50)
```

Comment: CASE being a keyword in T-SQL in SQL Server, should be enclosed in quotes.

Comment: @Vikdor - you're asbolutely right, I completely overlooked that.

Comment: Is there a way (syntax) for altering the table in the cmd prompt screen? - I am currently trying this and building my database and hopefully the change will go through

Comment: @Anima - absolutely, look into the `sqlcmd` utility.  You can run SQL scripts from the command line.

Comment: So i tried to create the column from the command line but it keeps telling me either the table itself doesn't exist or that i don't have permission - and i am sure that i have permission. And when i execute the same alter command in server management studio it goes through because when i try to execute it again it tells me that the column cannot be specified more than once.

Comment: @Amina - please edit your original question with your `sqlcmd` code.  There must be something wrong with that statement.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `Alter table` statement instead of `Create`

If you can't get the `Alter` statement to work for some reason, you could also `drop` the existing table and `create` a new one with the new field, but all your existing rows will be lost.

If you're using SSMS, you can `Design` the table instead of `Edit` to add the column.

Comment: I tried doing that but my problem is when i try to execute it will not update the table with the changes and when i build my database the alterations to the table are being ignored.

Comment: @Amina -Define what you mean by "when I build my database" - are you using some other tool here that you've not mentioned?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ok so i have all these tables and stored procedures and i make any changes to a stored procedure or a table i have to build the whole database and load with the info. Here is where i believe my problem is - that when i build my new changes to the table are not overwriting the info of the old table (Case table with the new CaseName column added to it.)

Comment: when you say 'build the whole database,' are you dropping and recreating the objects with SQL script?  If so, you could be overwriting any changes you've made.

Answer (score 1):

you should try this

```
 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Case]

    ADD CaseName NVARCHAR(50)
```

You are trying to create another table `Case` but one already exists that's why you have an error. When you want to edit a table, you have to use `Alter table`

Answer (score 0):

`ALTER` is what you need to investigate (`F1`)

An alternative is.
Create a new table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Case2]
(
    CaseId                  UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    CaseNumber              NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CourtId                 INT NOT NULL,
    DateOpened              DATETIME NOT NULL,
newcolumn               INT NULL    
)
```

Move data from existing table into the new one

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Case2]
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Case]
```

Then

```
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Case]
```

Then in management studio right-click 'Case2' and re-name it 'Case'

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking for the existence of the column prior to adding it, especially important when you work with migration scripts.

Here is how I usually do it:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns  WHERE Name = N'ColumnName' AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'TableName'))
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].TableName ADD ColumnName NVARCHAR(512) null
END
```